# jQuery ajax return always error on simple post

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I am banging my head against the wall with this problem. I am using JQuery 1.6.2 to use the AJAX method to a very simplified HTTP server running on a separate sub-domain. If I just POST a plain HTML form I get the correct output, but of course I want to make it nice with Javascript.

So I used the AJAX method as setup below:

```
$('.send_sample').click(function () {

        var request = $.ajax({
            url : "http://removedurl:8080/SAMPLES",
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'text',
            crossDomain : true,
            cache : false,
            accepts : 'text/plain',
            data : {username : '<?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>', first_name : '<?php echo $_SESSION['first_name']; ?>', last_name : '<?php echo $_SESSION['last_name']; ?>', company : '<?php echo $_SESSION['company']; ?>', sequence_id : '', filename : '', sample_id : '', quantity : '', output_file : '', delivery : '', email_copy : ''},
            success : function (return_value) {
                console.log(return_value);
            },
            error : function (error_info) {
                console.log(error_info);
            },
            complete : function (complete_jqXHR, textStatus) {
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });

        console.log(request);

    });
```

Notice the url was removed but everything else is the same including the port 8080 (trust me the server accepts the HTTP requests on 8080.

So when I open fiddler and I run this page, the request goes out and comes back absolutely fine in Fiddler. I even see the correct output which is just the word TRUE. You can even see the whole response raw here:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Length: 8
Server: Indy/9.0.18

TRUE
```

as I said before, this HTTP server this software uses is very simple. But JQuery on return goes directly to Error with no other description. One thing I also get is a small message if I debug in Chrome that says:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://removedUrl:8080/SAMPLES. Origin http://192.168.2.140 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Does anyone know what could be causing this.

Also, I have incrementally added the fields in the *ajax* method of JQuery: *dataType, crossDomain, cache, accepts*... just to see if it makes a difference.

Thanks!

Comment: `dataType : 'text',`? it "looks" like you are trying to post json (but that is not valid json in data: of course), or valid text really.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use jsonp to make cross site requests....
Setting crossDomain:true will not help beacause the browser blocks replies caming from external domains.
This is a well known javascript limitation, but, as i said, you can get rid of it using jsonp.
You can google it, you'll find plenty of resources!
Note that you'll need to modify your server "http://removedurl:8080/SAMPLES" in order to have jsonp responses.
If you do not have access to the server you'll have to rely on server side proxy (PHP/ASP.Net, etc.)